# How to use set row and column delimiter in flat file connection manager editor in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

How to use set row and column delimiter in flat file connection manager editor in SSIS

These 2 below paragraphs in one flat file. I want to convert these 2 paragraphs into 2 tables by using SSIS package.

META_DATA1 and META_DATA2 these are table names.

NAME;VALUE - column names for 1st table.
DEPARTMENT;VALUE - column names for 2st table. Please help.

```
#META_DATA1;NAME;VALUE
META_DATA1;"IT";"1"
META_DATA1;"COMPUTER";"2"

#META_DATA2;DEPARTMENT;VALUE
META_DATA2;"IT";"1"
META_DATA2;"COMPUTER";"2"
```

Output:
META_DATA1

| NAME | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| IT | 1 |
| COMPUTER | 2 |

META_DATA2

| DEPARTMENT | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| IT | 1 |
| COMPUTER | 2 |

Expected Output:
META_DATA1

| NAME | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| IT | 1 |
| COMPUTER | 2 |

META_DATA2

| DEPARTMENT | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| IT | 1 |
| COMPUTER | 2 |